# Query a specific time-range and alert at specific time of the day

Tags: elastalert

I need to run a rule at 2 am, querying logs from 0 to 2 am, and alert if matches are found.

So far all the rules I created are frequency rules, but I don't know how to achieve the specific time range for the query, and a specific time for the alert, can someone please help?

(I guess the ANY type could let me add my time range as part of the filter....but then how can I run the rule at 2 am every day?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The now is take the time of the server.

```
filter:
 - range:
   "@timestamp":
      "from": "now-2h"
       "to": "now"
```

Answer (score 0):

In UTC:

```
filter:
  range:
    "@timestamp":
      gte: "now/d+0h"
      lt: "now/d+2h"
```

Comment: You forget the - one the range. The correct is - range:

Answer (score 0):

if you want your alert to be effective for specific hours only, you can
create an enhancement that drop the alert if the current time doesnt match your needs
check
https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/adding_enhancements.html

regards